# Use Bazel with cyclic dependencies between libraries and variating strip_include_prefix attributes of these libraries

Tags: c++, include, bazel

I am quite new to build Tools and especially to Bazel.

I tried to use Bazel for C++ Code.
I faced the problem that I had cyclic dependencies between libraries. In order to solve this I placed these into the same cc_library rule. Unfortunately this led to a new problem. I need the strip_include_prefix attribute in all of my cc_library rules. 
This prefix is not the same for the libraries which are now combined in one cc_library.

How can I circumvent this Problem?

Comment: I think you will have no choice but to reorganize your file hierarchy so that the libraries share the same strippable include prefix.

Comment: Hm ok. That will be quite complicated since the code base is quite large and there are a lot of developers involved.

Comment: Alternatively, if the cyclic dependency is not present in the public headers of the libraries, then you could have three libraries. One with the source and private headers for both libraries, and two header-only libraries, each with their own strippable prefixes.

Comment: Hello Frank, Thanks for the help. I found the possibility to use the includes attribute. Here I added the paths which I used before in the strip include prefixes. Is this something that should be avoided?